# vscode python intellisense and submodule of alias

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

When I use VsCode with the Microsoft Python extension, intellisense is working very well, except in a specific case. I'm wondering if it is a bug or a misusage of my side.

Say that I have a module `foo` and a submodule `foo.bar`. They can themselves be deep into a broader project, so I might want to import them with an alias. Something like `from a.b.c import foo`.

When using the submodule , i'd like to use it's full name `foo.bar` and not just `bar`, just for clarity.

Therefore, I get something like that

```py
from a.b.c import foo
import a.b.c.foo.bar

# foo and foo.bar exists and are correctly imported. Intellisense does not work
```

When I do so. Everything works as intended. Python loads the modules, they are accessible with the wanted syntax and mypy correctly do static type checking. Only issue, VsCode is not able to recognize that `foo.bar` is indeed a known submodule I and do not have intellisense available. I found the following workaround to work, but I don't specifically like it.

```py
import a.b.c.foo
import a.b.c.foo.bar

foo = a.b.c.foo

# foo and foo.bar exists and are correctly imported. Intellisense works.
```

Is there a better way? Is it a vscode problem?

I do not want to import `foo.bar` into `foo`'s `__init__.py` file.  That will lead to circular import as `foo` might have other submodules required by `foo.bar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with the Python extension for VS Code.

One workaround is to use the `as` keyword to give the submodule a different name, like this:

```py
from a.b.c import foo
import a.b.c.foo.bar as bar

# Then you can use `bar` instead of `foo.bar`
```

This should allow intellisense to work correctly for the `bar` submodule.

The Python extension team is aware of the problem and is working on improving support for submodules with aliases in future releases.